# Laravel 5 - web and API Route conflict

Tags: api, laravel-5

In one of my website in laravel. I facing error 419 when i called login api below my search web route
Route::get('/{address_1}/{address_2?}/{address_3?}/{address_4?}');
Route::post('/{address_1}/{address_2?}/{address_3?}/{address_4?}');

And Below Api Route

Route::post('login', 'Auth\PassportController@login');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\PassportController@register');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel, a 419 HTTP error code is usually a sign that you are missing a CSRF token.

If the 'API' routes:

```
Route::post('login', 'Auth\PassportController@login'); 
Route::post('register', 'Auth\PassportController@register');
```

Are in your `web.php` file then this is likely because the `RouteServiceProvider` wraps the routes in your `web.php` file inside the `web` middleware which has the CSRF middleware enabled.

If this is the case, you will either need to include a CSRF token in your POST request, move these routes to the `api.php` routes file, or add the `register` endpoint to the `$excludes` array of the `VerifyCsrf` middleware.

**update**
Actually, your search routes are going to cause a lot of grief.
Given the fact that they can match **any** URL with one to four segments, your API routes are getting swallowed by these. 
What you will need to do is alter your RouteServiceProvider to register web routes last and then put your search routes last. 
This way, your pre defined routes will be registered before your “catch-all” search routes.

Comment: Hello @james I have put this route Route::post('login', 'Auth\PassportController@login'); 
Route::post('register', 'Auth\PassportController@register');  in api.php

Comment: Thank you for help @james i am very closer from my issue can you guide me how to my search route define in catch-all which you said it. - thanks

Comment: It is already basically a catch all, at least for a url with 4 segments. If you want it to do something else then you’ll need to post another question that is specific to the issue you have. As far as this issue goes, I believe the answer above should resolve your issue.